# I have issues connecting to Internet in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, internet, connection

I am dual booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10.

It can't connect to the Internet on Ubuntu 12.10. I have not had any way to update anything for it to try and connect it.

It would be nice if I could connect, because I need it for my schooling.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? What devices are you using? Can you connect to the network but not to Internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble connecting to you wireless try going to edit connections. then go to IPV6 setting and change method to Ignore.

If that doesn't help try to find a way to install "WICD network manager". This could be accomplished by plugging into you network directly.

If you still have a problem you are probably looking at a driver error for you wireless network card.